# How can i secure my JSON data on client side

Tags: javascript, security, cryptography, client-side

I have a scenario where i am sending the JSON data from the server side and storing it(in some cases) in browsers local-Storage, but i want that no one could access that data directly(from local-storage)

and the real problem is the project is accessible offline also for those stored data, Hence,

1. if i am encrypting the data on the client side then the logic and key will be on the client side only so any body can access that.
2. if i am writing the logic on the client side and storing the key at server-side then my project will not be functional offline.

I am confused a lot about what to do? any idea what best i can do in this situation?

Comment: any alternative ways??

Comment: You can't process any data you don't want to show the the user on their computer.